# Android ListView image resize

Tags: android, listview

I have a lazy-loading ListView populated with images gotten over the network. The list rows are set to wrap_content, so once the image loads it resizes and the full scale image will be displayed. It looks great when scrolling down, but when scrolling up the rows resize and force the bottom rows off the screen. How can I prevent this jumpy scrolling while scrolling up?

----- EDIT:

The images are comics of varying sizes. Some are 2 or 3 frames where they aren't very tall. Others are single frame comics where they are much taller. The image needs to take up the full width and the height should not cut off any of the comic.

Comment: Can you fix the maximum height of the images?

Comment: I cannot. I can only fix the width without skewing the images too much.

Comment: You can set the `ImageView` scale type attribute if you worry about skewing.

Comment: I've done that. I created a custom ImageView that does resizing based on the bitmap dimensions. I had to do that because it needs to take up the fill width but set the height to wrap content around the image.

Comment: perhaps you can use setOnScrollListener to determine when your list is scrolling (more important when its idle), and when it becomes IDLE, iterate through the visible views in your ListView and set the ImageView's visibility to VISIBLE (in your getView set them initially to INVISIBLE or GONE).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution. When I receive the image, I get the width from the parent then set the height of the image view to parentWidth * bitmapHeight / bitmapWidth. That way the resizing occurs as the row's view is created and the list doesn't jump around as much once I know the size of the bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all images downloaded are expected to be around the same size, a good solution most developers use is to use a "dummy" image until the real image is loaded. This image will exist locally so it can be loaded almost instantaneously. In the `getView` method, show this dummy image until the real image is downloaded, and then simply replace it. This will prevent your rows from resizing.

Comment: The images aren't the same size though. It's comic strips so some of them are 3 comic strips that aren't very tall. Some are a single comic frame that can be up to 4x the height of the strips.

Comment: Do you have any way of knowing the size of the image you're about to download? If you don't, do you at least know the maximum height? Otherwise, your heights are going to be jumping around as you scroll and it's not going to look pretty.

Comment: After I download the image, I have access to its size. The problem is calculating the resized height before the image's layout phase. During the layout phase the ImageView handles it.

Answer (score 0):

you have to see this [link](http://www.ryangmattison.com/post/2011/12/15/AsynchronousImageProvider.aspx) It downloads images in the background thread. Images are being cached on SD card and in memory,  It decode images with inSampleSize to reduce memory consumption and also try to handle recycled views correctly. Play a fake image when image are not completely downloaded. "sorry fo the music!!"

Comment: I already have the memory consumption and cache management under control along with the view recycling. The only remaining problem is the image sizes.